# Recover Same Wordpress Admin Password

Tags: database, wp-admin, password

I have a wordpress page that i'm trying to gain access to. I currently have access to the phpadmin database and I can easily create a new password. But I'm actually looking to see what the actual password is. There is only one user account, which is the admin. But i'm able to create other users accounts if needed. Is there anyway i'm able to crack the md5 salt password?

Comment: There is no stored password, just a **hash** of it. And the whole point of a hash is that you cannot "go backwards", it works just in one way.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. This is not possible. The password is btw, not encrypted only once, but twice with md5.

---

There are some cases where you type the password to the database, and for the short time, it will not be encrypted at all. :)

The very first time the admin authenticate itself again, the password will be correctly encrypted.

You may try that when you can.

Comment: thanks for the response. I think I might try my luck at just plain old brute force.

Comment: @gshustle, this way you are asking to understand the security problem of sharing the WordPress installation and database. You may update that title. Other way it looks like you try to hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a password cracking tool but this seems borderline unethical. I'm not sure that I understand the reason you would need to know the password at all if you aren't the owner of that account.